# Python import module from imported module issue

Tags: python

I have a project structure like that:

```
main.py
src\
  foo.py
  bar.py
```

And I am trying to import `foo.py` from `main.py`.

```
# main.py
import src.foo

# I also tried
# from src import foo
# or
# from src.foo import *
```

But `foo.py` imports `bar.py`.

```
# foo.py
import bar

# also tried
# from bar import *
```

But it has ModuleNotFoundError.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'
```

It worked when I did in `foo.py` something like this:

```
import src.bar
```

But I don't want to do that every time I import something. Why can't the imported module use its own parent directory and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: `from . import bar`

Comment: No. He is trying to run the module, I'm just trying to import it.

Comment: ^^ I dont want to do that every time. There must be a way to import it directly. I remember doing it. As a package it shouldn't be dependent on the importing module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your (sane) options are:

```
import src.bar      # Absolute import
```

or

```
from . import bar   # Relative import
```

`import bar` doesn't work in Python 3 because it has fundamental problems. Imagine a tree like:

```
spam\
  math.py
  eggs.py
```

If `eggs.py` needs the *built-in* `math` module, and does `import math`, on Python 2, it doesn't get the built-in, it gets `spam.math`. And it has no reasonable way of getting the built-in `math` at all (aside from a `__future__` import that gives you Python 3-style absolute imports).

```
from . import bar
```

is *the* way to reference a sibling module without explicitly naming the parent package. Use it.

Comment: Insane options include modifying `sys.path` so your own directory is part of it; it's not a sane option though, as it could lead to a given module getting imported twice independently, as it would be visible under both `src.bar` and `bar`.

Comment: Thanks. So basically you're saying I can't do that.

Comment: @OneNose: I'm saying `from . import bar` is correct, and does what you requested. Other solutions start at bad, and get worse. The only way `import bar` works is if you downgrade to Python 2, which I don't recommend for multiple reasons, starting with it being end of lifed nearly a year ago.